# Mongo DB - newly created documents are not inserted in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am using mongoose to create a new record. Sometimes, the new record doesn't sit at the end of all the existing documents, rather in the middle at a random place.

Am i missing something? This is the insert code:

```
      app.post("/api/books", (req, res) => {
         console.log("POST ROUTE HIT!");
         console.log(req.body);
         db.Book
           .create(req.body)
           .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
           .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
      });
```

I have a delete route too. Why are my new records inserted at random places sometimes, and other times they are inserted at the end?

Comment: How did you get to know that the records are inserted at random order? From your app? Does your app show records based on a sort order?

Comment: How do you see that your records are being placed at the end or randomly anywhere?

Comment: I think this is an issue with the sorting when you get your records. You have to sort with time. So, you can get the latest to old or old to latest.

Comment: I am able to see it in the database using ROBO3T. And that is how my app renders them. I haven't sorted it by any order. I am expecting the newly added documents will be inserted at the end, like in SQL?

Comment: It might be inserted at the end as you wish but you have to get it by sorted order. If you don't sort then it returns on a random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your newly created documents are inserted in default internal sort order (or [natural order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-natural-order)), The mongodb find query doesn't always sort the documents by default until unless you don't pass the sorting. It will return the records from the storage engine in natural order

As mentioned in [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/):

> **Result Ordering**
>
> Unless you specify the sort() method or use the $near operator,
>   MongoDB does not guarantee the order of query results.

So if you want to view/get all your documents sorted by _id/created then you need to put that in query manually.

```
db.getCollection('books').find({}).sort({"_id": -1})
```